A specific pattern occurs on numbers whose factors are coupled emirp.
Yesterday I asked Google if 403 is prime. The result showed that it has factors 13 and 31. So I wondered and wrote a little code that finds prime numbers which is also a prime when their digits are reversed. Such prime numbers are also referred to as emirps. Then I multiply emirp numbers with their couples E.g. (13x31), (17x71),(37x73), (79x97) etc. Here is the plot of the first 246097 composite numbers whose factors are coupled emirp numbers.
here is a quick and dirty way to test.
python
$pip install sympy matplotlib

from sympy import sieve
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# finds primes up to 100000
sieve.extend(100000)
arr = []
for prime in sieve._list[5:]:
    # reverse the prime
    rvrs = int(str(prime)[::-1])
    # find if  reverse in list
    if rvrs != prime and rvrs > prime and rvrs in sieve._list:
        arr.append(prime*rvrs)
plt.scatter(np.arange(0, len(arr), 1), arr, c=np.log(arr), s=.1, cmap="gnuplot2")
plt.yscale("log") # log plots are only for dealing with the exp growth. pretty rendering.
plt.xscale("log")

The plot shows that these numbers follow a specific pattern, does anyone have an idea why this was happening? And does this help anything?

Can you explain what the chart is? EG Is $(13, 403)$ going to be a point on the chart? $\quad$ I'm surprised that the chart grows so quickly,  I would have expected the chart to look something like $y = x^2$ instead of $y = x^3$.

The plot is the product of coupled emirp numbers. eg (1331), (1771), (37*73)...

@ChrisLewis exactly! the matplotlib deals with the x-axis as indices $[0,\ldots,\text{length of an array}]$ if it is not provided additionally. I use the log plot because numbers are growing exponentially and that makes the plot harder to investigate. colors just the $\log(arr[i])\rightarrow [0, 1]$ in some sense to make it prettier

Argh, sorry, I deleted my comment instead of editing. Could you just clarify exactly what is on each axis?

@ChrisLewis x-axis = $[0,\ldots, n]$ n is the number of elements in the array. y axis is the array that contains the product of two prime numbers which is their reverse.
$(x, y) \rightarrow [(0, 13\times 31 = 403), (1, 17\times 71 = 1207), \ldots]$ does this make it clear?

Have you compared this to the (visually similar) pattern you get when you replace "prime" with "odd"?

@ChrisLewis after your suggestion I have, thanks. I replaced the prime with even, odd, and all the positive numbers up to n. They are following the same pattern in general. The shape is strictly about the product of the number with its digits reversed version.  But the consistency in the blobs, 3, 2, 1 piece of blobs while increasing, and the density increase in the primes are still an open question for me.

This answer is a bit long-winded but hopefully useful!
We can describe the pattern in the plot as a series of banded "blobs" (OP's term in the comments but I can't think of anything better!). This appear to lie on a single straight line. Each blob seems to be about the same size, and have the same structure; the main difference is that the blobs become more densely populated as we move to the right.

To bring in some notation, first define $\text{rev}(x)$ to be the number formed by reversing the digits of $x$ in base $10$. Let $\left(x_n\right)$ be the ordered set of natural numbers $x_n$ satisfying

$x_n$ is prime
$\text{rev}\left(x_n\right)$ is also prime
$\text{rev}\left(x_n\right)>\left(x_n\right)$

and let $y_n=x_n \cdot \text{rev}\left(x_n\right)$.
The plot shows points $\left(n,y_n\right)$ with log scales on both axes.

Why do we get blobs?
Each blob corresponds to numbers $x_n$ with a different number of digits. Ignoring primality considerations for a moment, the smallest odd number with $k$ digits is $10^{k-1}+1$ and the largest $10^k-1$; so the $y_n$ corresponding to $k$-digit emirps lie in the interval $\left(10^{2k-2}+2\cdot 10^{k-1}+1,10^{2k}-2\cdot 10^k+1\right)$. These intervals are disjoint.
Although the $x_n$ are strictly increasing, the $\text{rev}\left(x_n\right)$ are not, and nor are the $y_n$; because of this, the blobs get "filled in" to some extent.

Why do they have bands?
Looking closely at a blob (this may need a plot with smaller point markers), we see it is made of a series of bands; each blob starts with $4$ bands, then $3$, then $2$, then tapers down to $1$.
These occur because of the different pairings of start and end digit. The smallest $x_n$ with $k$ digits are those starting with $1$ and ending with one of $1$, $3$, $7$ or $9$; these form the four bands we first see in a blob.
The next bands are the $x_n$ starting with $3$ and ending with one of $3$, $7$ or $9$, and so on.

Why are the blobs the same size?
Vertically, the blob for emirps with $k$ digits occupies the interval $\left(10^{2k-2}+2\cdot 10^{k-1}+1,10^{2k}-2\cdot 10^k+1\right)$, as stated above. On a log scale, each of these has roughly the same height.
To see what happens horizontally, let $C(N)$ be the number of $x_n$ less than $N$:



$N$
$C(N)$
$\log_e{C(N)}$




$10^2$
$4$
$1.4$


$10^3$
$18$
$2.9$


$10^4$
$120$
$4.8$


$10^5$
$823$
$6.7$


$10^6$
$5592$
$8.6$


$10^7$
$40829$
$10.6$


$10^8$
$308618$
$12.6$



We see that $\log_e{C(N)}$ grows approximately linearly as $N$ increases through powers of $10$. This explains why the blobs we've seen so far have similar sizes in both directions on the log plot.
The fact the blobs are approximately the same size also explains why they lie on the same straight line, and also why they get more densely populated (their size is the same, but they contain more points as $n$ increases).
However, I'm not sure how long this pattern continues; according to Wikipedia, "It is an open problem whether there are infinitely many emirps" (although, of course, no citation is given for this statement). If the density of emirps is something like the density of primes, we would expect this behaviour to go on, but I've no idea how such a conjecture could be proved.
